# How to get substrings from a string in android?

Tags: android, regex, string, xpath, substring

Hello I have a long string and its having html tags like "
" and "**" and** ,I want to get values from this strings,can anyone give me solution how to get values from it?
my string is:

```
<strong>1 king bed</strong><br /> <b>Entertainment</b> - Wired Internet access and cable channels <br /><b>Food & Drink</b> - Refrigerator, minibar, and coffee/tea maker<br /><b>Bathroom</b> - Shower/tub combination, bathrobes, and slippers<br /><b>Practical</b> - Sofa bed, dining area, and sitting area<br />
```

**my try**

```
int start = description_long.indexOf("Food");
                    int end = description_long.indexOf("<br />");
                    String subString = description_long.substring(start,
                            end);

                    System.out
                            .println("===============MY SUB STRING FROM STRING============="
                                    + start
                                    + ""
                                    + "============end======="
                                    + end + "");
```

i want to get values of **Food & Drink** and **Bathroom**,can any one please tell me how to get these values in a seperate string in android programatically.

Comment: What have you tried yet? Maybe you should take a look at possible operations on strings.

Comment: see my edit to see my try buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this but values must end with `<br />`

```
    String key = "<b>Bathroom</b>";  //<b>Food & Drink</b>
    int start = htmlInput.lastIndexOf(key);
    String value = htmlInput.substring(start + key.length(), htmlInput.indexOf("<br />", start));
    System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Better you could use a regular expression or try to parse.

`<a[^>]*>([^<]*)<[^>]*>(.*)`

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: hi sir thank you ,please help me,i have tried but not getting proper values..:( please please.